# Do I Need To Replace My Raspberry Pi Camera?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, raspi-config

I know that there are several threads here that discuss this issue, however none of the solutions have made any difference. Anyway, when I plug in my RPi Camera into my B board, I get this error:

```
mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, 
including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

The red light on the camera stays on but will not take a picture. I've updated and upgraded everything. I've also reconnected the ends of the camera ribbon to ensure a proper connection but still nothing has changed. This is the same error I get in my B+ board which I also upgraded and updated.

I've tried disabling and then reenabling the RPi camera in the Raspi-Config, switching the pin used for 1-Wire to pin 18 (as seen [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/what-causes-enospc-error-when-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module)), and a few other methods.

Could it be just the ribbon, or is it the camera board itself? Or maybe there is a software workaround?

Let me know if you need anymore information!

Comment: Is your power supply good enough? Inadequate power causes all sorts of problems. The B+ has an undervoltage detector, the red power LED blinks off; if it stays on steadily then the power is ok.

Comment: Yeah, I just double checked it on both the B and the B+. Both use a 5.5v power supply from a charger. I still get that same error posted above.

Comment: Do any messages show up in `dmesg` after plugging it in?

Comment: No, nothing but the message stated above.

Comment: Have you tried doing a basic electrical test of the ribbon cable? Continuity test each pin at each end to make sure there are no breaks. Many cheap/affordable multimeters include an audible continuity test that can make testing the cable relatively painless. Those cables tend to be pretty sturdy, but it's worth eliminating as a factor.

Comment: Hi- I suspect you replaced your camera? If not please tell us how you fixed the problem and accept and answer. Thanks (I had similar issue... I had to get a new camera)

Comment: I'm ordering a new one. There was no successful fix unfortunately. Should I add my own answer?

Comment: You should answer your own question if you have a fix. Note buying a new camera is not a fix.

Comment: I've had this happen to me twice. From all my research I'm guessing that at one point I carelessly hot-plugged a usb from my device and the current surge fries something in the module.

Comment: This fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57119934/7106915

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only fix for me was to purchase a new camera.

Comment: I had the same problem, also had to get a new camera. I suspect there is chance of some kind of electrostatic damage to the camera that is possible and the errors you specified are the symptoms.

Answer (score 3):

The "Sunny" connection on the camera board is probably loose. It is the yellow-ish piece of PCB. Try pushing it into the camera board.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it. I pressed the Sunny connection in some more but nothing seemed to pop back into place. I still get the same mmal error though. I guess I might just have to bite the bullet and get a new camera. What's odd is that the camera LED is on whenever I submit the command in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Same story. Try completely disconnecting the sunny one. Then reconnect. it fix for me.