# PiCam Not Working (At All)

Tags: camera, raspicam, raspivid

As I recently bought the Picam, I tried capturing an image with :

```
raspistill -v -o file.jpg
```

But I got this error :

`"No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board"`

I already tried disconnecting Flex cables, Sunny connector and plugging them back, updating my system, rebooting...

But I still get the same error...

What should I do to fix it ? Do you think my camera module is probably broken ?

Comment: I've seen these error messages quite a few times here. First of all, see if any of [these search results](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=No+data+received+from+sensor.+Check+all+connections%2C+including+the+Sunny+one+on+the+camera) or [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=including+the+Sunny+one+on+the+camera+) answer your question.

Comment: Does the LED on the camera light up when plugged in?

Comment: Yes, the Red Led lights on, so there IS actually a hardware contact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I Need To Replace My Raspberry Pi Camera?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32659/do-i-need-to-replace-my-raspberry-pi-camera)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your ribbon cable on the PI is connected in the right direction?  And by that I mean, did you look at the CSI connector and make sure you're matching the pins up with the contacts on the ribbon?  I only say this because when I first bought mine I was not completely sure which way it was supposed to go.  lol

If they are indeed inserted correctly I would bet that the camera is broken...  But that's just my two cents

Comment: I guess I plugged all correctly.
Would it harm if I try the other way ?

Comment: I do not believe it would harm anything.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I had to buy a new module since I couldn't find any solution to fix it. Turns out the camera is a delicate module so it breaks easily.

Comment: Indeed, I was aware of that, but I was very careful, so I think I got it already broken... -_-

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
sudo raspi-config
```

in terminal to enable the camera and then try again.

Comment: You probably mean "raspi-config" ? I already enabled it, that's not the source of the problem.