# Why am I getting 'camera component couldn't be enabled' with raspistill?

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspicam

I am getting those errors when I try to take a picture with raspistill. Until now, it took pictures anyways.

```
$ raspistill -o test.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

I ran `app-update` and `app-upgrade` to install the newest firmware when the pi was on the Internet the last time (a month ago), but that didn't help.

Anyone get any ideas?

Comment: Has your camera ribbon cable been dislodged?

Comment: No, shouldn't have been. @CoderMike

Comment: Are you using Raspbian Buster?

Comment: Im running on Strech @CoderMike. Was the newest when I set the Pi up.

Comment: I followed this answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/13765/107269 already @DmitryGrigoryev. Didnt help either.

Comment: I would flash the latest Buster to another SD card, full update. Try that. Also re-seat camera cable.

Answer (score 1):

Change the settings in /boot/config.txt

```
gpu_mem=128
start_x=1
```

Reboot and re-test.

Comment: Nope, did not solve the issue.

Comment: Then you have to look at whether the hardware is broken or not connected properly. BTW, what OS and what kernel version are you running?