# To play a pi camera

Tags: raspicam

I am trying to play a picamera in raspberry pi 4 using vlc with raspivid/raspistill. When I give a command: `sudo raspivid -o cam.jpg` then some errors come,

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

Comment: have you enabled the raspberry pi camera port in `raspi-config`?

Comment: Are you using the latest Raspbian Buster fully updated? Is it a genuine Pi camera?

Comment: Why are you using sudo? Using the camera doesn't need sudo. Also run `vcgencmd get_camera` to check it's enabled.

Comment: Hello...Yes, I have enabled a camera using "sudo raspi-config".  Also, I am using a latest updated RPi4 Buster.  Also run vcgencmd get_camera that show me "supported=1 detected=1". This means my picamera is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The camera is probably running out of GPU memory. Check config.txt in the /boot/ folder. The gpu_mem option should be at least 128.

Possible Duplicate of : [What causes ENOSPC error when using the Raspberry Pi camera module?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/what-causes-enospc-error-when-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module)

Comment: Yeah...It's working. But I have a question that Max. & Min. how much value of gpu_mem can take in Raspberry pi4 especially?

Comment: @miteshmahera If it solve your problem, then you should accept this answer.

Comment: 512mb ..128MB will probably be enough.