# Raspbery camera, video stream at 3280x2464

Tags: camera, raspivid, v4l2, gstreamer

According to [this page](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/fov.html) Raspberry camera v2 can produce video stream with resolution of 3280x2464. However, all my tries with `raspivid` and `gstreamer`/`v4l2` fails.

Knows someone how to reach this video resolution ?

My tries and errors:

1. with `raspivid`

   ```
     pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspivid -v -md 2 -w 3280 -h 2464 -fps 15 -o prueba.yuv

    "raspivid" Camera App (commit 6e6a2c859a17 Tainted)

    Camera Name imx219
    Width 3280, Height 2464, filename prueba.yuv
    Using camera 0, sensor mode 2

    GPS output Disabled

    bitrate 17000000, framerate 15, time delay 5000
    H264 Profile high
    H264 Level 4
    H264 Quantisation level 0, Inline headers No
    H264 Fill SPS Timings No
    H264 Intra refresh type (null), period -1
    H264 Slices 1
    Wait method : Simple capture
    Initial state 'record'


    Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
    Preview window 0,0,1024,768
    Opacity 255
    Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
    Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
    Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
    Flicker Avoid Mode 'off'
    Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
    Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
    ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
    Camera component done
    Too many macroblocks/s: Increasing H264 Level to 4.2
    Encoder component done
    Starting component connection stage
    Connecting camera preview port to preview input port
    Starting video preview
    Connecting camera video port to encoder input port
    mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.ril.video_encode:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
    mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.ril.video_encode:in:0(OPQV))0x10533e0 (ENOSPC)
    mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
    mmal: main: Failed to connect camera video port to encoder input
    mmal: Out of resources (other than memory)
    Closing down
    Close down completed, all components disconnected, disabled and destroyed

    mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
   ```
2. with gstreamer/v4l2:

   ```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src do-timestamp=true ! video/x-h264,width=3280,height=2464,framerate=15/1 ! fakesink

    Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
    Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
    Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
    New clock: GstSystemClock
    ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to allocate required memory.
    Additional debug info:
    gstv4l2src.c(658): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
    Buffer pool activation failed
    Execution ended after 0:00:00.471647017
    Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
    Setting pipeline to READY ...
    Setting pipeline to NULL ...
    Freeing pipeline ...
   ```

Comment: Read section 6.2 hardware limits in same document you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar error to this:

```
 mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.ril.video_encode:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
```

because I still had motion set to run (from another attempt at steaming), check this:
[What causes ENOSPC error when using the Raspberry Pi camera module?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/what-causes-enospc-error-when-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After solve the issue, can you capture video at 3280x2464?

Comment: I have not tried yet as I am just using the HQ camera to stream to youtube and I am just doing it at  1280x720. Did you look at the 6.2. Hardware Limits on that page to make sure the rest is falling in range?