# Raspberry Pi Cam V2 (not) compatible with Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: camera

When I connect a V2 camera module (8 MP) to the Raspberry Pi Zero [W], I get

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

I tried the tests and fixes discussed in [What causes ENOSPC error when using the Raspberry Pi camera module?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/what-causes-enospc-error-when-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module/29177#29177)
and they suggest a defective camera.

But:

- The V2 works fine with the Raspberry PI 4.
- The V1 works fine with the Raspberry PI 4.
- The V1 works fine with the Raspberry Pi Zero.
- The V1 does not work with the Raspberry Pi Zero.

So I do not suspect a hardware problem.

Comment: Oh, Typo! 
Instead of "The V1 does not work with the Raspberry Pi Zero."  
it should be "The V2 does not work with the Raspberry Pi Zero."  
Sorry for the confusion.